# Use fields with NA values for model training with tensorflow

Tags: pandas, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am trying to create a machine learning model with tensorflow using dataset available at
https://www.kaggle.com/imnikhilanand/heart-attack-prediction

The csv file looks like below (please note I have replaced `?` with `.` so that it is easier to parse with pandas)

```
age,sex,cp,trestbps,chol,fbs,restecg,thalach,exang,oldpeak,slope,ca,thal,num       
28,1,2,130,132,0,2,185,0,0,.,.,.,0
29,1,2,120,243,0,0,160,0,0,.,.,.,0
29,1,2,140,.,0,0,170,0,0,.,.,.,0
```

When I parse this with panda, the `.` is read as `NaN` in the dataframe of pandas

Feeding this data is creating problems since any operation with `NaN` will be `NaN`.

My problem with the data is unavailable data, is there a way I can feed this kind of data to the model and get the results.

One of the solution I found was to replace it with some number (like 0) but doing that wrecks the accuracy of the model, I want to avoid that.

Comment: You can drop rows in which there are some missing data or drop a column. This is not the best solution since you can end up with small amount of data which may not give you satisfying result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [data](https://www.kaggle.com/imnikhilanand/heart-attack-prediction), and realizing that the *vast majority* of the values in the three attributes `scope`, `ca`, and `thal` are missing, the most certain thing you should do is to remove these attributes (columns) completely from your modeling.

There is a (huge...) area of machine learning dealing with data imputation, but it is most certainly not applicable here - it is usually applicable when only *some* (i.e. a small minority) of your values are missing, which is far from being the case here.

> One of the solution I found was to replace it with some number (like 0) but doing that wrecks the accuracy of the model, I want to avoid that.

Understandably so; if you do insist on experimenting in this direction, try replacing the missing values with the mean (or median) of the respective attribute (this is one of the simplest data imputation approaches).

In case you intend to use a deep learning model here, notice also that a dataset of only 294 samples is rather small for such an application...